# Printing and using Var within a ListObject forloop

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-interop, listobject

I currently have this C# code that has access to table1. I am having an issue however with Var listRowsValue and var lr. How can I print these and subtract 1 off of ListRowsValue and not view "System._ComObject" as an output? How can I resize ListObject to not check another row at the end of the count?

```
var listRowsValue = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].ListObjects["table1"].ListRows;

for (int CurrentRow = 0; CurrentRow < listRowsValue.Count; CurrentRow++)
{
    if (xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].ListObjects["table1"].Range[CurrentRow, 2].value == -1)
    {
        xlSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "YES!";
        //lr.Range.Clear();   
        var lr = listRowsValue[CurrentRow];
        Console.WriteLine("CURRENT ROW: " + lr);//Why does this not work?       

        //MoveEmUpOne();
        //How do I resize the total listRowsValue count here so it doesn't check another row at the end?
        //EXAMPLE: ListRowsValue = ListRowsValue - 1;
        //CurrentRow = CurrentRow - 1;
    }
    else
    {
         xlSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "NO!";
    }
}
```

Old VBA code I'm converting from:

```
For CurrentRow = 1 To Tablesize
    If Lo.ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange(CurrentRow) = -1 Then
        Ros(CurrentRow).Range.Clear
        MoveEmUpOne Lo, CurrentRow, Tablesize
        Tablesize = Tablesize - 1 'table didn't really get smaller, but number of "real"rows decreased by 1
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow - 1 ' check this row again -- stuff from below might need cleard
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of VSTO is quite different from regular C# libs because it depends on COM intensively.

`lr` is a [ListRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.listrow_members.aspx) object.

Use `lr.Range.Text` to get the text in it.

```
Console.WriteLine("CURRENT ROW: " + lr.Range.Text);
```

See [`Range.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.text.aspx).